# replace a function in C with a macro function

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

i have a function `isEmpty()` and i want to replace it with with this `Empty()`.

```
int isEmpty(char *s)
{   return s[0]=='\0';
}
```

Should i replace it like this?

```
#define isEmpty() Empty()
```

Comment: If you are trying to get rid of the function completely, maybe you meant to do this: `#define isEmpty(s) ((s)[0]=='\0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have a function `isEmpty` as defined, you need to pass a parameter to it:

```
#define Empty(s) isEmpty(s)
```

But you might want to achieve it without any function:

```
#define Empty(s) ((s)[0]=='\0')
```

Comment: No! i have to replace the function with another one. So, the wrong part was that i have to type first the name of the function that i want to replace and the function i already have right?

Comment: Don't confuse macro with function. Macro is just a symbol that is replaced by the macro body literally (up to parameters and some special tokens). So in `#define` block the first thing is the macro name, and the second - the macro body. So when you want to use macro you are using the macro name.

Comment: i don't want to get rid of the function completely, i just want to replace the function with another name let's say...

Comment: ohh now i see. so the first part `Empty()` is the macro name, the one that i will call inside my program. and every time i will call it the program will replace it with the `isEmpty()` right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It will be replaced by the preprocessor, before the compilation is taking place (it is important point to understand).

Comment: Yes! Now i understood it! Thanks a lot Eugene